# Accessing the original TWebRequest object in a Delphi SOAP Server

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, httpwebrequest

Summary: How do you access the original [TWebRequest](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/HTTPApp_TWebRequest.html) object in a Delphi Soap Server Application ?

My web service publishes a service `ITest` with a method `CallMe`:

```
ITest = interface(IInvokable)
['{AA226176-FFAD-488F-8768-99E706450F31}']
  function CallMe: string; stdcall;
end;
...
initialization
InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ITest));
```

This interface is implemented in a class:

```
TTest = class(TInvokableClass, ITest)
public
  function CallMe: string; stdcall;
end;
...
initialization
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TTest, TestFactory);
```

How do I access the original `TWebRequest` object inside of the implementation of this method ? E.g.  If I want to check what cookies were set, or read other properties on the request:

```
function TTest.CallMe: string;
begin
  // how to access TWebRequest object
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Web.HTTPApp,
  Soap.WebBrokerSOAP;

function TTest.CallMe: string;
var
  WebDispatcher: IWebDispatcherAccess;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Supports(GetSOAPWebModule, IWebDispatcherAccess, WebDispatcher) then
    Result := Format('You are calling me from: %s', [WebDispatcher.Request.RemoteIP]);
end;
```